# Algorithm for shortest prefix matching?

Tags: algorithm

Given String p and list of strings find the shortest string for which p is the prefix.

I know the brute force approach but what will be the optimal approach?

e.g.

```
p = "foo bar"
list = {"foo bar 1",
        "foo bar foo bar",
        "bar foo foo foo bar bar"};
```

Should return "foo bar 1"

Comment: Please explain why it would not return `"foo bar 1"`.

Comment: what if `list` contains `"foo b"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have a search space (in your case, a relatively constant `list`), then generating a trie or some other suitable structure would help searching a lot. Start with Wikipedia which explains this in enough detail to get you started:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Here's an image from the above article that uses words (which readily extends to using strings of any kind or even non-strings):

[image: A trie for keys "A", "to", "tea", "ted", "ten", "i", "in", and "inn".]

The article provides some performance comparisons with other suitable structures, which is helpful in your case.

Note that if list changes sufficiently enough, then the returns of this approach might diminish or you can even have worse performance compared to brute-force.

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach, which you might have already been thinking of, is basically just to check the length of the string after each pass.

Using psuedo-C#:

```
int length = 0, index;
string p = "foo bar"
string[] list = new string[]{"foo bar 1",
    "foo bar foo bar",
    "bar foo foo foo bar bar"};
for(int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++) {
    if(list[i].Contains(p)) {
        if(list[i].Length < length) {
            index = i;
            length = list[i].Length;
        }
    }
}
MessageBox.Show("The shortest one is " + list[index]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to run it for a *single* `p` then the straight-forward approach:

1. Find all strings in the `lst` that start with `p`
2. Find the shortest among them

it is already optimal it is `O(n)` in time, `O(1)` in space, in Python:

```
shortest_with_prefix = min((s for s in lst if s.startswith(p)), key=len)
```

If there are multiple `p`, but the `lst` is the same then you could preprocess `lst` into a prefix tree ([Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)) to make multiple searches faster, in Python:

```
from pytrie import StringTrie # pip install pytrie

trie = StringTrie.fromkeys(lst)
shortest_with_prefix = min(trie.iterkeys(prefix=p), key=len)
```