# Splitting a connected sentence into individual words

Tags: algorithm

Lets say I have the following String: "loveyou", I need to write an algorithm to split it to: ["love", "you"].
I have a dictionary with all possible words.. I thought about going through all the possible options and check if they are words:
"l oveyou", "lo veyou", "lov eyou", "love you"..
This would result in an O(n^2) runtime.. Is there a more optimized algorithm?

```
public int splitSentence(String s) {
  for (int i=1; i<s.length(); i++) {
     if (isAWord(s.split(0, i) && isAWord(i, s.length()) {
          return i;
     }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: split it into `exactly` two words? 
And are you sure the algorithm you gave is `O(n^2)`?

Comment: what if one word contains another one ?

Comment: I believe that the algorithm is O(n^2) because the first loop iteration is (1 + (n-1)) .. the second one (2 + (n-2)).... ((n-1) + 1)... Which means n+n+n...+n=n^2

Comment: @Edin lets assume this case isnt given

Comment: @Qkwe Ok, but could you confirm whether you're only supposed to solve this for strings of exactly two words?

Comment: I see only one `for loop` here. Are you assuming that `isAWord()` method is non-trivial?

Comment: Even if answered, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338652/algorithm-for-shortest-prefix-matching might be a possible duplicate.

Comment: I don't think it is easy to tell if you can parse sentences unambiguously if you allow sentences of arbitrary length. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_correspondence_problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve your problem `O(mn)` where `m` is the length of the longest word and `n` is the length of the input stream. I would need to think on this a little more, but as a rough idea sketch as a variation of Knuth-Morris-Pratt:

1. Use a  [prefix tree/trie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for storing the word list.
2. Keep a list of *open positions* in the Trie.
3. Before reading a new character, create a new open position at the root of the tree
4. For each open position, move it in the tree according to the input character.

When you reach a leaf, you have found a word. Since you move at worst `m` positions each time, for each of the `n` input characters, you get `O(mn)`, or really `O(n)` when the length of the words is small compared to the length of the input stream.

Note, that this works under the assumption, that you want to split on shorter words first. Otherwise it needs adopting.